# Google Drive API Advanced Sharing Settings

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to change the advanced sharing settings via API as seen here: http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Disable-Copying02.jpg

As it states here: http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/14/you-can-now-disable-downloading-printing-and-copying-for-any-file-stored-in-google-drive/ this should be possible, but I cannot find anything in the Documentation?

Could you point me to the right part of the documentation or give a short example?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Drive API provides a `files().update` option as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

In the request parameters, the `labels.restricted` property can be set to `True` so that download, printing, etc. is disabled, and `writersCanShare` property should be `False` so that editors cannot change access.